# How to save data in a different format in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, date

I notice that MySQL save date as 0000-00-00 format. But in my application I have validate date for this  00-00-0000 format. I notice that date is not saving properly as different formats. Can I change mysql data format to 00-00-0000 format?

Comment: What is the problem? Give people the luxury to choose?

Comment: I get a string like 12-05-2012 I want to convert this to 2012-05-12

Comment: PHP strtotime() and date() play well together.  For your internal representations of DATETIME, use the ISO-8601 standard.  For your client presentations, choose any format that make sense.  This article may be helpful. http://www.experts-exchange.com/Web_Development/Web_Languages-Standards/PHP/A_201.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `00-00-0000` format is not entirely clear; it could be `dd-mm-yyyy` for instance.

You can simply convert the date you have like so:

```
$mydate = '24-12-2012';
// create date object by using a known format
// see manual page for all format specifiers
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $mydate);

// format date object in yyyy-mm-dd
echo $d->format('Y-m-d');
```

See also: [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) [`DateTime::format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

Comment: Thanks Jack. this works for me. Can you leave explanation of your answer. I didn't know Datetime class can do this.

Comment: @kiriappa You're welcome; I've added links to the respective methods I'm using to create and format the date object. The manual contains many examples of how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use MySQL `str_to_date` function

```
INSERT INTO yourtable (datefield) VALUES (str_to_date('01-02-2007', '%d-%m-%Y'));
```

Answer (score 1):

As **@Jack** explained it is one of the correct way you can choose and

> at the time of select date from database you can use
>   [DATE_FORMAT(date,format)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

Answer (score 0):

You can't.
Instead of that you have to convert your custom format to database format and back.

To store it in the database you can use `explode` PHP function.
To when selecting, you can format mysql date format using `DATE_FORMAT` mysql function.